# 110 volt AC 2 pin socket with one slot longer than other? can anyone tell me why. I have a jug with a plug also one side wider than the other,?

Tags: ac, mains

I have an electric jug 1500 watt 110 v AC. The 2 pin plug with parallel pins are slightly different, One pin is the same size width and length all the way from start to finish. The other pin is the same length and the same width until it gets to near the small hole is in the end where it enlarges slightly. It will not fit into a normal 2 pin socket. I have two 110 v transformers. one has a socket that will take the jug plug (one slot wider than the other. the other transformer socket has slots exactly the same size. Some 110 v 2 pin appliances will fit into either socket but the jug one will only fit in the enlarged one.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is a polarized plug and socket.

The longer slot in the socket and wider pin on the plug are the Neutral connection.  The shorter slot and narrow pin are the "Hot" or "Line" connection.